# Can not use one to many realationships in reports to show information. (should be simple)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 2 tables, that are connected with a one to many relationship.

I have a BikeID (FK) in a bikeSold table with another table called BikeInfo (PK). However when I go to create a report I can just not get the "BikeName" to be shown instead of the (FK/PK)!

(here is the image of the table however please take note that you cant see the many sign however when right clicking it does say that it is)

[Relationship table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ggzm.png)

When I generate the report I get the PK where as I need to show the BikeName, I have tried Dlookup, SQL and Queries and just none of them seem to work. (admittedly it has been a while since I worked with databases)

I thought this was going to be one of the simple things to do!

Comment: Did you by any chance add a look up to your tables? If not, just use a querry to join the tables and get all the details for your report. If you did, oh deary me.

Comment: I feel stupid. To join all the tables in a query is too obvious. I have been trying to do this for two days. Thank you. If you add this as an answer I will set as correct answer.

Comment: You have been looking at the same data so long you stopped seeing it, happens all the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query should work quite well for you, for example:

```
SELECT a.BikeName, a.Cost, b.DateSold
FROM BikeSold b
INNER JOIN BikeInfo a
ON b.BikeID = a.ID
```

The report can then be based on a saved query with all the data you need.